# Como configurar o arquivo host para direcionar para o servidor de uma máquina virtual "virtual box"?

Tags: laravel, virtualbox, virtualhost

Eu tenho uma máquina virtual windows 7 usando virtual box. Dentro dessa máquina eu tenho um projeto de estudo laravel. Dentro dessa máquina eu acesso esse projeto através da url `"lara/"`, configurada em routes.

Eu gostaria de saber como direcionar uma requisição da url da máquina física para dentro da minha máquina virtual. O que fiz foi:

1. Peguei o IP da máquina virtual - **192.168.56.1**
2. Configurei o arquivo `etc/hosts` da máquina fisica para apontar para a máquina virtual quando a URL `"lara;"` for solicitada.  `192.168.56.1 lara/`

O meu processo não está funcionando. Eu sei que poderia usar o Vagrant mas eu queria saber como fazer isso sem essa ferramenta.

É possível?

Comment: Olá, zwitterion, qual o servidor? (Apache, Nginx, Artisan, etc?) Essa url `lara` é provavelmente parte de uma aplicação em um virtual host do seu servidor http dentro do Virtual Box. Você precisa expor esse virtual host para o mundo (apontar algo no `etc/hosts` da máquina *host* não faz diferença se o *guest* não estiver expondo nada no IP dele).

Comment: Oi Anthony. Estou usando IIS na minha máquina física (Win 7). Na máquina virtual estou suando laravel com apache. Eu simplesmente criei um link no arquivo etc/hosts da minha máquina física que aponta para o ip da máquina virtual. Na máquina virtual coloquei na opção bridge.

Comment: Veja as configurações do apache então  (`https.conf` e companhia. Você só vai conseguir acessar a URL de fora do virtual box depois de tornar esse vritual host visível).

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16112487/664577) em Inglês.

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui fazer e foi mais simples do que pensei.
Vou compartilhar os passos, caso alguém precise:

1. Configure a placa de rede da máquina virtual para "bridge"[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Abra a máquina virtual e verifique o ip[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]. ou pode escolher a configuração de ip fixo. **Nota**: esse é o terminal de **DENTRO DA MÁQUINA VIRTUAL**
3. Abra o arquivo `hosts` da **MÁQUINA FÍSICA**  em `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc/hosts` e passe o ip da máquina virtual. Em seguida faça o refresh do DNS com o seguinte comando `ipconfig /flushdns` 
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Agora é so digitar no **browser de sua máquina física** o ip da máquina virtual ou o Alias escolhido no `host` e está pronto. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
5. **Nota**: Para fazer qualquer usuário do grupo de rede ter acesso, basta seguir os passos 3 e 4 na máquina de cada usuário.
6. **Nota**: Na máquina física estou usando **IIS**. Na máquina virtual estou usando **Apache**.